# No keyboard accessibility on LWC tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have run into an accessibility requirement in building an LWC where the user must be able to use the keyboard to tab across tabs in a tabset (what a mouthful!).

I have a lightning-tabset with three lightning-tabs wrapped inside. Within each tab, I have a different LWC that loads different content.

What I have found is that, when the user see's the tabs on screen, the first tab is focused by default but when they tab on the keyboard, it goes straight down to the content, rather than to the next tab in the tabset.

Is there a way I can make it so that when the user hits the tab key, it goes straight to the next tab, rather that to the content first?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to solve this in HTML but because the LWC lightning-tabset is an out of the box component you can't change the HTML it generates.  You'll have to report this accessibility issue to Salesforce for them to fix.